# rails 3 disable select_field with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
    jQuery ->
  $('#welcome_carmodel_id').parent().hide()
  carmodels = $('#welcome_carmodel_id').html()
  console.log(carmodels)
  $('#welcome_carmake_id').change ->
    carmake = $('#welcome_carmake_id :selected').text()
    options = $(carmodels).filter("optgroup[label=#{carmake}]").html()
    console.log(options)
    if options
      $('#welcome_carmodel_id').html(options)
      $('#welcome_carmodel_id').parent().show()      
    else
      $('#welcome_carmodel_id').empty()
      $('#welcome_carmodel_id').parent().hide()
```

**what this code do:** 
   it hides the select_field B until I select something from select_field A
in other words, the carmodels selector is hidden until I make selection from carmakes and if carmakes have no carmodels the carmodels selector is also hidden.

**Problem:**  How do I change this field from hidden to disabled? I need it to be disabled not hidden. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using jQuery version >= 1.6  use prop() method to disable an form field

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
   $('#select_field B').prop('disabled',true);/* false to enable*/
```

If < jQuery 1.6

```
   $('#select_field B').attr('disabled','disabled');

   /* enable again*/
   $('#select_field B').removeAttr('disabled');
```